# Recursive function iterates more than expected

Tags: python

i am trying to make a program that will iterate through all the files and folder in a directory. My program works up til the point where it is supposed to terminate. When the if statement in update_dir() triggers the "Done" print it continues to call the unzipper() function and i cannot for the life of me understand why.

This is the folder structure on my drive:

```
D Drive
+-- 64 Test Directory Simple
|   +-- 1
|   |   +-- 2
|   |       +-- 3A
|   |       +-- 3B
|   +-- A
|       +-- B
+-- ...
+-- ...
```

This is the ouput in the console:

```
Unzipper will stop unzipping when is has unzipped archives equivalent to 66% of the available space.
Free space on harddrive is 1GB
D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple --- 
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1 --- 
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1\2
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1\2 --- 
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1\2\3A
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1\2\3A --- 
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1\2
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1\2 --- 
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1\2\3B
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1\2\3B --- 
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1\2
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1\2 --- 
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1 --- 
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple --- 
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple\A
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple\A --- 
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple\A\B
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple\A\B --- 
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple\A
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple\A --- 
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple --- 
 == D:\
 == D:\
Done!
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple --- 
 == D:\
 == D:\
Done!
 == D:\
 == D:\
Done!
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1 --- 
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple --- 
 == D:\
 == D:\
Done!
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple\1 --- 
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple --- 
 == D:\
 == D:\
Done!
 == D:\64 Test Directory Simple
 == D:\
 --- D:\64 Test Directory Simple --- 
 == D:\
 == D:\
Done!
 == D:\
 == D:\
Done!
```

This is my code:

```
#Dependas
from os import scandir, path
from time import sleep

#Inputs
print("Unzipper will stop unzipping when is has unzipped archives equivalent to 66% of the available space.")
#pace = input("How much space is available? (in GB) - ")
space = 1
print(f"Free space on harddrive is {space}GB")
#location = input("What is the file structure location? (e.g c:/weg)")
location = "D:\\64 Test Directory Simple"
stop_location = path.dirname(path.dirname(location))
print(stop_location)

#Variables
space *= float(space)*float(0.66)
used_space = 0
last_completed_dir = ""
dirs_visited = []

#Functions
def update_dir(location_arg):
    location = location_arg
    print(f" == {location}")
    print(f" == {stop_location}")
    if location == stop_location:
        print("Done!")
    else:
        unzipper(location)
    
def dirs_visited_func(check_dir):
    for entry in dirs_visited:
        if entry == check_dir:
            return bool(1)
            break
    return bool(0)

def unzipper(location):
    directory = scandir(location)
    print(f" --- {location} --- ")
    sleep(0.25)
    for entry in directory:
        if entry.is_dir():
            #print(entry.name)
            if not dirs_visited_func(entry.path):
                #print('Not visited')
                #print(f'Now go to {entry.path}')
                update_dir(entry.path)
                break
        #else if zip
        #else if 7zp
        #else if rar
    dirs_visited.append(location)
    update_dir(path.dirname(location))
    
     
unzipper(location)
```

Comment: `update_dir` is called from `unzipper`.  After it prints `Done`, it *returns* to the caller, i.e. `unzipper`, which then continues from point after the call.

Comment: Okay, not really related to the problem, but `return bool(1)` and `return bool(0)` is the weirdest thing I've seen today. `return True` & `return False`. Similarly, `float(0.66)` is redundant and `float(space)` unnecessary; `0.66` is already a `float`, and multiplying an `int` by `float` gets another `float`, so `space *= float(space)*float(0.66)` can simplify to `space *= space * 0.66` (assuming you really meant to multiply `space` by itself times 0.66, which strikes me as a titch odd).

Comment: And while we are at coding style: Your function `dirs_visited_func` can simply be replaced by `entry.path in dirs_visited`. And the `break` after the `return`-statement doesn't really make sense because the code will never reach that position.

Comment: Thank you for the comments people. Using a ``return`` statement to stop the function from running more was what i needed.